# Determining the Stationary Distribution for a Markov Chain with a Countable State Space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I am trying to determine a stationary distribution for the following problem:

Find the stationary distribution of the Markov chain with the countable
state space ${0, 1, 2,...,n,...}$, where each point, including $0$, can either return to $0$ with probability $1/2$ or move to the right $n \to n+1$ with probability $1/2$.

I know a stationary distribution must satisfy $\pi P = P$ and from the ergodic theorem $lim_{n \to \infty} p_{ij}^{n}= \pi_{j}.$  How can I apply these principles to determine the stationary distribution in this specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the system $\pi= \pi P$.
\begin{align}
\pi(0) &= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^\infty \pi(i)\\
\pi(1) &= \frac{1}{2} \pi(0)\\
\pi(2) &= \frac{1}{2} \pi(1)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Comment: Do you just use this recurrence relation to write a general solution for $\pi_{n}$ and that's the stationary distribution?

Comment: @user75514 That is how the stationary distribution is defined.